# Log ModelState Errors to app insights for each Bad Http Request using Web Api 2.x

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, azure-application-insights, webapi, appinsights

I know I can create an ActionFilter  where I get the ModelState from the current actionContext.
I could use the TelemetryClient or ILogger (if it works for old web api) and do manual errors adding to the app insights properties. But then I will have Twice the same 400 error http request. Intercepted by azure and mine from the filter...

What Telemtry related interface do I have to implement where I have also access to the ModelState so I can just hook into the whole telemtry tracking process?

Neither **ITelemetryInitializer** nor **ITelemetryProcessor** has access to the ModelState!

What is the correct way then?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have much options apart from registering a Global ActionFilter or ResultFilter in your Global startup to capture ModelState and Track Requests via TelemetryClient (remember to declare it as static to avoid multiple instances of TelemetryClient). To eliminate **duplicate** request logging by the inbuilt one, you can disable the RequestTrackingTelemetryModule in ApplicationInsights.config like below (commented out that). And of course you need to now log all requests in your new action filter, apart from which have model validation errors since now you disabled inbuilt one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <TelemetryModules>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
    <!--<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />-->
  </TelemetryModules>
  <TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel" />
  <TelemetryInitializers>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
  </TelemetryInitializers>
  <InstrumentationKey>00001111-2222-3333-4444-555566667777</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

Comment: but then other requests implicit logged by app insights will not be tracked!

Comment: other requests like?

Comment: @HelloWorld wanted to check if you have any update on this.